use same request or response for multiple RPC
I encountered the error

path-to/my_service.proto:25:3:"c.BookRequest" is used as the request or response type for multiple RPCs.

I have created a couple of RPC that have same request structure.
rpc GetTitle(BookRequest)returns (TitleResponse){}
rpc GetPrice(BookRequest) returns (PriceResponse){}

message BookRequest {
  string book_id = 1
}

The same applies to RPC that returns book list, I would like to used BookResponse for all of them
message BookResponse {
  repeated Book books = 1
}

Do I have to create almost identical requests and responses for them? Or there is anyway to reuse them?

You may use the same message for multiple RPCs. You describe the error without showing what you did to generate it. Your proto is invalid. There is no service; Message should be message;. int isn't a valid scalar type. Please revise your question to show a more accurate summary of what you did and what happened.

It's possible that your error results from duplicate message BookRequest definitions as the error appears to be a Java error (prefixed by a class variable) rather than a protoc error.
